# How to detect memory Leak in Java application outside the heap?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, swt, jna

We have a Java Application that uses SWT and some other DLL through JNA in Windows 7 environment.

We have seen the JVM process's memory usage increases with time but the JVM heap is relatively steady with normal GC activity.

We suspect there are some memory leak from SWT and/or JNA/DLL, but cannot be sure why or where.

Is there any tools on the Windows platform that can help to detect this kind of problem?  Or any facility in Java platform that can help to resolve this problem? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The most common leak with SWT is the application failing to `dispose` of things like `Color`

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 there is a command line switch: `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=<value>`, where value can be `off`, `summary` or `detail`.

You can set this to `detail` and then you can query it using `jcmd`.

There's some official documentation on this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html). This feature is fairly limited though, but it may just help find the cause.

---

Failing that, a crude but effective way of identifying the source of the problem is to replace the dll with a dummy version (or even a non-native dummy) and see if you can reproduce the same problem.

Comment: "Since NMT doesn't track memory allocations by non-JVM code, you may have to use tools supported by the operating system to detect memory leaks in native code." To my untutored eye that sounds like it isn't going to help with tracing memory leaks outside of the JVM heap. If I'm wrong could you elaborate as I'd love to learn more on this topic.

Comment: @Joeblade Native memory is allocated by JVM code for other purposes too, it isn't just the heap you can examine with it. But yeah, it's got its limitations and it may not work in this case. It's still a feature worth knowing about.

Comment: @bizclop :) yeah that's why I was hoping to coax you into elaborating. I hadn't heard of it before so was curious about it.

Comment: Yeah worth knowing what NMT can do. Can you guys suggest a windows's native solution then?